# Mesh issue - Seperate objects on rigged character moving apart when animated

Tags: mesh, shape-keys

I modelled the collar on my character seperately from the jacket.
Now when I change the pose, as the entire mesh is parented by automatic weights to the rig (rigify), the objects come apart as they are only connected by 'join mesh' and do not actually have common edges.

I'm wondering what the best solution for this issue is.
I've tried boolean, but this is messy.
Would shape keys work for this? Someone else suggested using mesh deform modifyer but this seems arduous for animating. Does anyone know a better solution?

Much appricated. Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: No, shape keys are not a good solution.  Weld the vertices if you want to use autoweights; otherwise, weight manually.  A mesh deform is a worthwhile technique to learn.  It's not arduous: you armature deform a manifold, non-rendering mesh deformer which then deforms the rendering mesh.

Comment: Hi. The mesh density for each objects is quite different. So manually welding them would probably be difficult / take ages. I will try weight painting - haven't done this before but I will give it a go. As for mesh deformer, I have no clue about that, but if you think it would be useful in an instance like this, then I will look in to that! Thank you!

Comment: You should not have edited the image formatting code for your question. I fixed it.